# Added WooCommerce admin product custom fields throwing warning

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, custom-fields

I have some code in child theme functions.php file, adding a couple of custom fields to WooCommerce Admin Product options. It has worked for a few years with no problem, but now I'm getting PHP warnings as follows:

> PHP Warning:  Undefined variable $post in /home/xxx/public_html/wp-content/themes/flatsome-cobra/functions.php(65) : eval()'d code on line 4
> PHP Warning:  Attempt to read property "ID" on null in /home/xxx/wp-content/themes/flatsome-cobra/functions.php(65) : eval()'d code on line 4

Here is the code:

```
<?php
// Add custom Theme Functions here

// Display Fields
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_inventory_product_data', 'woocommerce_product_custom_fields');
 
// Save Fields
add_action('woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'woocommerce_product_custom_fields_save');
 
 
function woocommerce_product_custom_fields()
{
    global $woocommerce, $post;
    echo '<div class="product_custom_field">';
    // Custom Part Number Text Field
    woocommerce_wp_text_input(
        array(
            'id' => '_part_number',
            'placeholder' => 'Part Number (Short SKU)',
            'label' => __('Part Number', 'woocommerce'),
            'desc_tip' => 'true'
        )
    );
    // Custom Part Ref Text Field
    woocommerce_wp_text_input(
        array(
            'id' => '_part_ref',
            'placeholder' => 'Part Ref (Schematic Ref)',
            'label' => __('Part Ref', 'woocommerce'),
            'desc_tip' => 'true'
        )
    );
    echo '</div>';
 
}

function woocommerce_product_custom_fields_save($post_id)
{
    // Custom Part Number Text Field
    $woocommerce_part_number = $_POST['_part_number'];
    if (!empty($woocommerce_part_number))
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_part_number', esc_attr($woocommerce_part_number));
    // Custom Part Ref Text Field
    $woocommerce_part_ref = $_POST['_part_ref'];
    if (!empty($woocommerce_part_ref))
        update_post_meta($post_id, '_part_ref', esc_attr($woocommerce_part_ref));
}
```

Please, do anyone know what changes are needed to get rid of the warnings?

I've suppressed warnings on the web page, but I guess this will need correcting for future PHP versions, I'm using PHP 8.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is a bit outdated since WooCommerce 3, try the following instead:

```php
// Display Fields
add_action('woocommerce_product_options_inventory_product_data', 'display_admin_product_custom_input_fields');
function display_admin_product_custom_input_fields() {
    echo '<div class="product_custom_field">';

    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id'            => '_part_number',
        'placeholder'   => __('Part Number (Short SKU)', 'woocommerce'),
        'label'         => __('Part Number', 'woocommerce'),
        'desc_tip'      => 'true'
    ) );

    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array( 
        'id'            => '_part_ref',
        'placeholder'   => __('Part Ref (Schematic Ref)', 'woocommerce'),
        'label'         => __('Part Ref', 'woocommerce'),
        'desc_tip'      => 'true'
    ) );

    echo '</div>';
}

// Save Field values
add_action('woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'save_admin_product_custom_field_values', 10, 1);
function save_admin_product_custom_field_values($product) {
    if ( isset($_POST['_part_number'])){
        $product->update_meta_data('_part_number', sanitize_text_field($_POST['_part_number']));
    }
    if ( isset($_POST['_part_ref'])){
        $product->update_meta_data('_part_ref', sanitize_text_field($_POST['_part_ref']));
    }
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your child theme (or in a plugin). Tested and works.

It should solve the PHP warning.

Comment: Thank you for the updated code. I've used it but I still see the PHP warnings on the web page - it's at top of right sidebar on every Grouped Product page on front end .
I'm confused as the code above relates more to Product Admin.

Comment: Yes, I didn't think it looked like this code should affect the frontend but it's strange the warning on the frontend is pointing at my functions file line 4.
Is it likely the problem is somewhere else in the functions file or is the warning totally misleading?

Comment: If you enable WP debug, the debug.log file will say exactly what the error is and where it is located…  I think that the error could be related to some code used for frontend (and maybe related to that custom fields). But I can't guess things by magic.

Comment: I found the problem - I had some php code in a sidebar widget and the problem was here. I probably would have found sooner if the warning didn't reference the function.php file. Thank you for your help, you helped rule out the functions.php file as being the problem.